# Perl use variable as a file name

Tags: perl, variables, filenames

How to create a file with name containing variables with underscore between them. I need to create a file with name like this $variable1_$vraiable2_$variable3.txt

```
@values=split(/\./, $line)
my $fpga_name=$values[0];
my $block_name=$values[1];
my $mem_name=$values[2];
my $memfilename="mem_init/$fpga_name_$block_name_$mem_name.txt";
open(WRITE_MEM_FILE, ">>memfilename");
print WRITE_MEM_FILE "$line \n";
```

Comment: You can write your first four lines more concisely like this: `my ($fpga_name, $block_name, $mem_name) = split(/\./, $line);`. You should also use the 3-argument form of open, lexical filehandles, and check the success of `open`, e.g. `open(my $fh, '>>', $memfilename) or die "Failed to open '$memfilename': $!";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply wrap all of the variables in curly braces:

```
my $memfilename="mem_init/${fpga_name}_${block_name}_${mem_name}.txt";
```

Keep in mind you need a `$` before `memfilename` in your open statement, otherwise you will just get the literal string:

```
open(WRITE_MEM_FILE, ">>$memfilename");
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether you need the intermediate array, and the three extra variables. If not, you can write the whole thing as:

```
my $memfilename = sprintf(
    '%s_%s_%s.txt',
    split(/[.]/, $line, 3), # whether you want 3 here depends on your input
);
```

If you do need the three intermediate variables, you can still skip the creation of the `@value` array and write something more legible than interpolating three variables into a string:

```
my ($fpga_name, $block_name, $mem_name) = split /[.]/, $line, 3;
my $memfilename = sprintf '%s_%s_%s.txt', $fpga_name, $block_name, $mem_name;
```

Using `sprintf` yields code that is much more readable than interpolating three variables, the braces, the underscores, the sigils etc.

Alternatively, you could also use:

```
 my $memfilename = sprintf '%s.txt', join('_', split /[.]/, $line, 3);
```

Again, whether you want the third argument to `split` depends on your input.

Finally, if you find yourself doing this in more than one place, it would help to put it in a function

```
sub line_to_memfilename {
    my $line = shift;
    # ...
    return $memfilename;
}
```

so if the format ever changes, you only need to make the change in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Indicate where the variable names begin & end by writing `${varname}`:

```
my $memfilename="mem_init/${fpga_name}_${block_name}_${mem_name}.txt";
```